# Site Search results are the same no matter the query

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, query

I am having trouble with the search in SharePoint 2013.

**The problem :**

I am running in to is that no matter what I search for in SharePoint, the results page populates that same exact documents in the same exact order every time. Also, these documents are totally unrelated to the specified search.

- What could be the reason for this problem?
- Is there a setting that I have enabled or disabled on accident?

Any lead way into what I should do would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you in a search center when you perform the query? Did you alter the default result source query?

Comment: Yes, no matter whether you use the search box or a search box web part, it still comes up with the same results.  I believe that I did alter the default result source query on an accident and now I'm not sure how to get it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Edit the Page that stores the search results
- Edit the "Search Results" web part
- Select "Change Query"
- In the Query text box, look for `{searchboxquery}`

If you don't see that, the search box query will not be included in the search results.